# Override behaviour of pressing "space" in PDF Kit view for OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos

It seems like the standard behaviour of a pdfkit view when pressing space is to switch pages. We want to use the space button for other events (playing audio in our case).

Setting the space as shortcut in the menu does only work before the pdfkit view is interacted with. After that the behaviour is always set to switch pages.

We have also tried to intercept the space key-down-event using this code:

```
if (!keyDownEventMonitor) {
    __weak IBBookViewController *weakSelf = self;
    NSEvent * (^monitorHandler)(NSEvent *);
    monitorHandler = ^NSEvent * (NSEvent * theEvent){

        BOOL handleEvent = weakSelf.view.window != nil 
                            && theEvent.type == NSKeyDown
                            && !theEvent.isARepeat;

        if (handleEvent) {
            switch ([theEvent keyCode]) {
                case 49:
                    [self audioPlayPauseBtnHit:nil];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return theEvent;
    };
    keyDownEventMonitor = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:monitorHandler];
}
```

but it does only extend the space functionlity so both the audio is played and the page is switched.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have other directions to go here.

Subclassing to override behavior. 
( keeping in mind that the behavior may be inherited from a superclass or part of a class that is a private ivar in the header for the pdfview class. )

Looking at the responder chain and which object really gets the keyDown message first. Intercept and forward, possibly changing key view temporarily.

Creating a cover view that handles the keyDown events you care about first and forwards other events to the responder chain.

Comment: A global event monitor or event tap is probably overkill.

Comment: Just solved it. I overrode (correct english? :)) the keyDown and KeyUp and inserted a custom callback to handle the space event locally in the view. In addition to the menu this work perfectly.